# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processClientReleaseResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android

I want to upgrade the version of my libraries, I get this error after click on Sync Now.

JAVA version is 1.8,
Android Version is 24,
Studio Version is 2.2, 
Gradle Version is com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

Libraries before upgrade:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Libraries after upgrade;

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

This is the error that I get.

[image]

This is the whole error.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleClientRelease]
```

Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForClientRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 13.098 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:1 warning
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: What's the `JAVA version`,`Android Version`, `Studio Version` and `Gradle Version`? Please edit in the question.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I've updated the question with other tools' versions.

Comment: Try `clean` task and `Rebuild` whole project?

Comment: if you are linux user, you should give permissions to execute this file. In linux via terminal go to path(where aapt located) and enter sudo chmod a+x aapt. Or give read permissions also

Comment: @OgnevZair My development is on Mac. How should I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: can u show whole stacktrace, maybe there are logs which points to problem

Comment: @OgnevZair I've added the stacktrace in question.

Comment: maybe you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043855/proguard-error-while-evaluating-instruction

Comment: @OgnevZair Great. It does help with my problem.